# How can I compare data from two links with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, compare

I want to compare and print genre_ids in the first link and id in the other link.

Sample:

genre_ids: [
18,
878,
]

{
id: 18,
name: "Drama",
},
{
id: 878,
name: "Science Fiction",
}

Result: Drama, Science Fiction

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=7196f61181cb7f5b0a28020cd3f603fb&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&item_count=14";

    var categories = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=7196f61181cb7f5b0a28020cd3f603fb&language=en-EN";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: categories,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (cat) {
                    $('#Movies').html(ListMovies(data, cat));
                }
            });
        }
    });

    function ListMovies(data, cat) {
        var card = "";
        var cats = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

            card += "<div class='col-sm-3'><div class='card'><img src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280" + data.results[i].backdrop_path + "' height='250px' class='card-img-top'><div class='card-body'><h5 class='card-title'>" + data.results[i].original_title + " <span>" + data.results[i].vote_average + "</span></h5><p class='card-text'>" + result should be here + "</p></div></div></div>";
        }
        return card;
    }
});
```

Comment: `var result = genre_ids.map(k=>data.find(p=>p.id==k).name).join(',')`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: genre_ids is not defined :(

Comment: I tried to var result = data.results[i].genre_ids.map(k=>data.find(p=>p.id==k).name).join(',') but it's not working. Error is Uncaught TypeError: data.find is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```js
function ListMovies(data, cat) {
        var card = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            let cats = [];
            cat.genres.forEach(elem=>{
                if(data.results[i].genre_ids.includes(elem.id)) cats.push(elem.name)
            })

            card += "<div class='col-sm-3'><div class='card'><img src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280" + data.results[i].backdrop_path + "' height='250px' class='card-img-top'><div class='card-body'><h5 class='card-title'>" + data.results[i].original_title + " <span>" + data.results[i].vote_average + "</span></h5><p class='card-text'>" + cats.join(", ") + "</p></div></div></div>";
        }
        return card;
    }
```